# Is there anyway to capture selenium test failed message like a timeoutexpection in TestContext?

Tags: selenium, nunit

I have code to capture screenshot on test failure. What I'm doing right now is naming the screenshot with *"TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.ID + "_"+ TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name"*. I want to add test failed message to it something like *"Message: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".applicationTitleSteps"}*". Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Please add more info about what you are trying to do. A code snippet would probably do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get read the Exception message as string by simply casting your Exception object. Perform string manipulation options like splitting to get the required value and concatenate with your current name, which you are giving for the screenshot while saving.
Your exception catching code should be like this, catch(exception ex).